# Getting a random object from a random amount

Tags: java, random

I have a small issue with a project I'm working on,

I have a list of a "Location" object, the size of this list is variable and depends on the users input. (getAllRed(arena) is a method that returns a list of locations).

What I want is to get a random location from this list and do something with it. I seem to be stuck here as the "amount" is a variable, usually, I use the following:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = 0;

for (int fi = 1; fi <= 1; fi++) {
    i = 1 + rnd.nextInt(1);
    if (i == 1) {
        // do something
    } 
    else { 
        //do something else
    }
}
```

But, because in my case the integer that goes in rnd.nextInt(HERE); is variable, depending on the size of the list, I can't use this.

How could I solve this?

This is the code I have right now:

```
int amount = getAllRed(arena).size();

Random rnd = new Random();
int i = 0;

for (int fi = 1; fi <= 1; fi++) {
    i = 1 + rnd.nextInt(amount - 1 );   
}
```

The amount - 1 is needed because Java will start at "0" I believe.

Let's say the list contained 3, this is how it would look:

```
int amount = getAllRed(arena).size();

Random rnd = new Random();

int i = 0;

for (int fi = 1; fi <= 1; fi++) {
    i = 1 + rnd.nextInt(amount - 1 );
    if(i == 0){
        return getAllRed(arena).get(0);
    }
    else if( i == 1){
        return getAllRed(arena).get(1);
    }
    else{
        return getAllRed(arena).get(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `- 1` is *not* needed, because `Random.nextInt(int max)` returns results in the range `[0, max)`, not `[0, max]`.

Comment: Lets say if the amount of Locations in the list was 3, I would want 3 options then. If Random.nextInt(int) starts from 0 and goes up to the max (3), wouldn't it be 4 objects that it goes through? (0, 1, 2, 3)      ** EDIT: I didn't exactly understand what [0, max) meant. Ok, thanks for the info!**

Comment: In math notation, `[0, max)` means `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., max-1`. (`[` and `]` mean *inclusive*, while `(` and `)` mean *exclusive*.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've always learned it as "[0,max[" that's why I wasn't sure what the ")" was for. Thanks for clearing it up to me though!

Comment: Oh. I actually didn't know there was another notation for it. Glad I could clear that up, though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
int amount = getAllRed(arena).size();    

Random rnd = new Random();
for (int fi = 1; fi <= 1; fi++) {
    int i = rnd.nextInt(amount);
    return getAllRed(arena).get(i);
}
```

`rnd.nextInt(amount)` will return an `int` in the range `[0, amount)`. (That's `0`, inclusive and `amount`, exclusive.)

However, you really shouldn't call `getAllRed(arena)` multiple times. (I don't know if the function is functionally pure or not.)

```
// assuming that getAllRed(arena) returns a List<MyType>
List<MyType> allRed = getAllRed(arena); 
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int fi = 1; fi <= 1; fi++)
    return allRed.get(rnd.nextInt(allRed.size()));
```

Another note is that `return` will break out of the `for` loop, so there's no point in even having it:

```
// assuming that getAllRed(arena) returns a List<MyType>
List<MyType> allRed = getAllRed(arena); 
Random rnd = new Random();
return allRed.get(rnd.nextInt(allRed.size()));
```

Yet another note is that your `Random rnd` should be kept somewhere global so that it won't be reseeded every time you use this function (perhaps with the same seed every time, which would make this not be random).

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me understand randoms a bit better and it solved my issue! Can't believe the solution was that simple ;).

Comment: Would storing the random at the start of my class be safe?

Comment: Yes. You would also want to initialize it (`Random rnd = new Random();`) only once (probably in the constructor). Then everywhere else you want to just use `rnd`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the Object at that index

```
//Determine size
size = getAllRed(arena).size();

//i will be 0 up to size -1
i = rnd.nextInt(size);

//return that index
return getAllRed(arena).get(i);
```

Comment: Ah yes, it's that simple! Thanks!